# Android - Unable to create new Android Project

Tags: android, eclipse

I have downloaded `Eclipse-Kepler` for android programming. For creating an android project when I choose `file->new` option,I don't find any android application project in the option to choose.
how I could find it?

Comment: You need [ADT Plugin](http://developer.android.com/tools/sdk/eclipse-adt.html)

Answer (score 0):

Visit [Android SDK's](http://developer.android.com/sdk/index.html)
 and [Eclipse Plugin for Android](http://developer.android.com/sdk/installing/installing-adt.html)

Answer (score 0):

Download the [Eclipse ADT bundle](http://developer.android.com/sdk/index.html). This way it would not be necessary to separately add the Android SDK.